# SQl Server - Which Inventory Tool ( Free )

Tags: sql-server

I would like  to get an inventory of all SQL Servers in my office and pertinent
meta information about them.

Need things like Version#, Instances, isClustered etc...

I prefer to automate this and run regularly.

I was hoping for some freeware a la SQLrecon versus hand scripting it via Powershell or vbs.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Flyer

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Freely available [Quest Discovery Wizard](http://www.quest.com/discovery-wizard-for-sql-server/)

Comment: Quest has some awesome tools

Comment: Quest is working on an upgrade to Discovery Wizard that has some new features that might help with what you want.  See Brent Ozar's blog for more information: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/tag/discovery-wizard/.

Comment: disclaimer: I work for the company behind this tool
https://www.sqldockit.com

To differentiate from other tools we have built snapshots and compare technology (ability to compare any setting of the server that you have today and how it was configured for example 2 months before, so you can see the differences, and you can compare two different SQL servers so you can find differences in the configuration) and Best Practices that checks your SQL server configuration with the best practices Microsoft recommended.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Ping 3](http://www.sqlsecurity.com/Tools/FreeTools/tabid/65/Default.aspx) is very similar to SQL Recon, but gives the extended information you are looking for. If you run it on Vista/Win7/2008, make sure to run it as admin or it may not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a similar solution to collect Windows and SQL Server inventory by gathering scripts from SQL Family and released it as a free tool at http://crazydba.com. The tool uses powershell to grab data from all servers and stores it in SQL tables and can be viewed using SSRS reports.  please check it and give me any suggestions to improve it.

Thnx